# how to send url in email without encoding 

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, url-encoding, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon Simple Email Service java API to send mail to receivers. 
I am sending URL in mail body inside  tag. 
My use case demands the user to double click on the URL received to prompt some action. (like confirmation mail)

Problem is the url gets encoded while receiving. On double clicking it gives page not found (404) error.

**Original URL** : http://something.com/confirm/email=abc@hotmail.com&regKey=somekey&confirm=true
When i double click on this URL on mail, the link is opened in address bar as :
http://something.com/confirm/email=abc%40hotmail.com%26regKey=somekey%26confirm=true

I am using **AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient**. Code is below :

```
    SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest().withSource(sourceAddress);

String confirmationURL="http://something.com/confirm/email=abc@hotmail.com&regKey=somekey&confirm=true";

            List<String> toAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
            toAddresses.add(toEmail);

            Destination dest = new Destination().withToAddresses(toAddresses);
            request.setDestination(dest);

            Content subjContent = new Content().withData("Confirmation Request");
            Message msg = new Message().withSubject(subjContent);

            // Include a body in both text and HTML formats
            Content textContent = new Content().withData("Dear please go to the following URL:"+
                    confirmationURL+"\n\n");

            Content htmlContent = new Content().withData("<p>Dear please go to the following URL:</p>"+
                    "<p><a href=\""+confirmationURL+"\">"+confirmationURL+"</a></p>");

             Body body = new Body().withHtml(htmlContent).withText(textContent);
            msg.setBody(body);
            request.setMessage(msg)
```

**UPDATE**

Just found, this problem is occurring only when recipient email is in **hotmail.com**. Why microsoft always have to do something differently ? Somebody help !

Answer (score 0):

Use the class java.net.URLEncoder:

```
String confirmationURL = URLEncoder.encode( "http://something.com/confirm/email=abc@hotmail.com&regKey=somekey& confirm=true", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Actually encoding is in hotmail recipient. I cant decode that.